# How to tell if user has released slider

Tags: godot

There's an issue on the github to add a released() signal to the slider node, but how would I do the same thing without it?

I want to have a slider, and when the user moves it it says "Value is now X" on a label on the screen.  But when I do it based on the 'value_changed(x)' it calls many times while the slider is being dragged.  I want it to set my only label when the player releases after sliding, or when presses and releases an area on the slider's range to select a new value without using the grabber.

Comment: It depends on the events you're "listening" too. onDrag (or something resembling) is used like you remarked for constant delivery of changing coords. onDragRelease(or something resembling) would only return the last position.
Sorry I don't know `godot`, so about the names of the event-handlers I'm probably mistaking and you've to find the right names.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is what I've come up with.  It doesn't literally let me know when the slider is released, but it tells me when the player stops editing the slider.  It still sends an alert if you pause briefly, but that is okay for my game.  It doesn't send continuous alerts like if you just use _on_HSlider_value_changed(), which is what I wanted to avoid.

```
var old = self.value #start value of slider
var timer_on = false

#will be called continuously while editing timer
func editing_slider(new):

    #only start a timer, if there isn't one already or you'll have a million
    if not timer_on:

        #start timer
        timer_on = true
        yield(get_tree().create_timer(.2), "timeout" )
        timer_on = false

        #if still editing, re call function
        if old != new:
            editing_slider(new)

        #done editing
        else: 
            print("slider set to " + str(value))


    old = new


func _on_HSlider_value_changed(value):
    editing_slider(value)
```

If you wanted to avoid the alert being called when the user pauses but hasn't released, you'd have to do do some kind of InputEvent check.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve what you want by overriding the _gui_input function. Attach a script to your slider, and then add this code:

```
func _gui_input(event):
    if (event is InputEventMouseButton) && !event.pressed && (event.button_index == BUTTON_LEFT):
        print("Released")
```

This will work whether the user releases the grabber or "releases an area on the slider's range to select a new value without using the grabber", and achieves what you want. However, if the code is meant to run on a device with a keyboard (e.g. a PC), then the user can also change the value via the cursor keys on the keyboard, and you may want to add support for that too.

Comment: Someone has downvoted without a comment. I've just tested again in the latest version of Godot (3.5.1), and the code still works just fine. I'm guessing they must have tried to implement `_gui_input` in a script attached to a non-`Control` node, such as `Node2D` or `Spatial` at the root level of their scene. Because `_gui_input` is a member function of `Control`, it can only be overridden in a script attached to a Control. So, attach the script either to the slider, as I described in my answer, or to a parent node that is/derives from `Control`. Otherwise, the function would never get called.